# Finding statistics on software development within GIS industry?

Tags: industry

I am trying to find some information, specifically poll results on platforms and languages used for GIS software solutions. I remember taking one but I cannot find the poll to see the results, it may have even been an Esri poll for all I know.

Can anybody point me to any of those results who may know where they had been squirreled away to?

Answer (score 2):

[Directions Magazine](http://www.directionsmag.com) has been running polls for over a decade.  You might be able to dig up some recent results on their website.  If you can't find what you're looking for, contact the editors: they are typically responsive and can find a poll or will create one.

(Disclaimer: I edited this magazine a decade ago, but I'm no longer formally associated with it.)

Answer (score 2):

Look on Daratech statistics http://www.daratech.com/research/gis/ but be careful, not free.

The same goes for http://www.technavio.com/content/geographic-information-system-gis-market-2007-2010

You can get some infos indirectly with a gis survey (limited mainly to commercial because no open source solution, no python,...). http://www.gisjobs.com/surveyresults/all.php

Also a discussion on "GIS and programming" on linkedin GIS group but you need an account and to suscribe to the group.